# Order by number of comments same table sql

Tags: mysql, sql

For some reason I mixed a table of posts with comments....So this is a post when `comment_of=0` and a comment when `comment_of= (number of a post)` like in this example

Posts

```
 id_post | id_poster | comment_of | post 
  23          3            0         hi       
  24          4            0        hello     
  25          5            0         how are you      
  26          3            25        lets go      
  27          3            24        come on      
  28          4            25        haha       
  29          3            25        go away  
  30          2            24        aint funny  
  31          3            23        lol  
  32          3            0         ok  
  35          3            0         here we go
```

Now what I want is to order the post by the number of `comments.comment_of` it has. DESC.

**MySql**  Something like this

```
  SELECT post 
  FROM posts
  WHERE comment_of=0
  ORDER BY (number of `comment of`) DESC
```

What I expect is something like this

```
  id_post | id_poster | comment_of | post 
  25          5            0         hi  (3 comments)      
  24          4            0         hello  (2 comments)   
  23          3            0         how are you (1 comment)      
  32          3            0         ok          (0 comments) 
  35          3            0         here we go  (0 comments)
```

Comment: `SELF JOIN` and then `COUNT` with `GROUP BY`.

Comment: your question is not clear   ..  for number of a post do you mean the id_post ???? ... why  the post hi you say 3 comments?

Comment: I mean, order the results by number of comment a post has in the same table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery in the `order by`:

```
SELECT p.post 
FROM posts p
WHERE p.comment_of = 0
ORDER BY (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM posts p2 WHERE p2.comment_of = p.id_post) DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `LEFT JOIN` on the same table and group by `id_post`, and get the count:

```
SELECT p.*, count(p2.id_post) as num
from posts p
left join posts p2 on p2.comment_of = p.id_post
where p.comment_of = 0
group by p.id_post
order by num desc;
```

Outputs:

```
+---------+-----------+------------+--------------+-----+
| id_post | id_poster | comment_of | post         | num |
+---------+-----------+------------+--------------+-----+
|      25 |         5 |          0 | how are you  |   3 |
|      24 |         4 |          0 | hello        |   2 |
|      23 |         3 |          0 | hi           |   1 |
|      35 |         3 |          0 | here we go   |   0 |
|      32 |         3 |          0 | ok           |   0 |
+---------+-----------+------------+--------------+-----+
```

Comment: I didnt see this answer. What  is better left joining or using a subquery? in efficiency?

Comment: @joe From [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/rewriting-subqueries.html): _"A LEFT JOIN can be faster than an equivalent subquery because the server might be able to optimize it better"_

Comment: @joe The query above gives you the count of comments, I don't know if you want it :)

Comment: @Syscall They probably forgot to write "*A LEFT JOIN can be **slower** than an equivalent subquery because the server might **not** be able to optimize it*". This is often the case for GROUP BY queries.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Well, probably. I still prefer `JOIN`, they are more readable, IMHO ;)